# How to use a relative path for a theme's favicon

Tags: 8

I'm trying to ship a favicon with my custom Drupal 8 theme, but I can't figure out how to specify its location relative to my theme's installation location.

Following [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/184852/58028) I've created a `config/install/MY_THEME.settings.yml` file containing

```
favicon:
  use_default: false
  path: '/themes/MY_THEME/static/favicon.png'
```

(I'm keeping all my theme's static files in a `static` subdirectory of my theme directory)

This works, but contains a hard-coded reference to the installation location of my theme. Hence, if a user decides to install the theme in `themes/contrib` or `themes/custom` instead of in `themes` the favicon won't be found.

Therefore I would like to specify a path relative to my theme's root directory or relative to the `MY_THEME.settings.yml` file. However, it seems that Drupal uses the server root (`/`) as a base when I specify a relative path, so `static/favicon.ico` ends up as `/static/favicon.ico` which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another idea for a workaround would be to overwrite the href property on runtime with [hook_page_attachments_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8), somethng like this:

```
function MYTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
     foreach($page['#attached']['html_head_link'] as $k => $v) {
          if (array_key_exists('rel', $v[0]) && $v[0]['rel'] == 'shortcut icon') {
                  $page['#attached']['html_head_link'][$k][0]['href'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . 'static/favicon.png';
          }
     }
}
```

or use the default favicon path (MY_THEME/favicon.ico), it will be taken, see this source:

```
// Generate the path to the favicon.
      if ($cache[$theme]->get('features.favicon')) {
        $favicon_path = $cache[$theme]->get('favicon.path');
        if ($cache[$theme]->get('favicon.use_default')) {
          if (file_exists($favicon = $theme_object->getPath() . '/favicon.ico')) {
            $cache[$theme]->set('favicon.url', file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url($favicon)));
          }
          else {
            $cache[$theme]->set('favicon.url', file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url('core/misc/favicon.ico')));
          }
        }
        elseif ($favicon_path) {
          $cache[$theme]->set('favicon.url', file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url($favicon_path)));
        }
        else {
          $cache[$theme]->set('features.favicon', FALSE);
        }
      }
```

Comment: This would need extra checks to see if the user has chosen not to use the theme's favicon.

Comment: i guess you can use the default location. theme_folder/favicon.ico - check the source here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/8

Comment: Using the default location seems like the easiest way to accomplish this. Thanks for your input!