# How to remove favicon

Tags: 8

How can I remove the drupal favicon, I have tried to change the theme settings and global settings but it's not changing anything because I have to put another link if I want to replace it with my own, but I don't want to replace it I want to remove it.

Comment: Try to remove file *favicon.ico* in themes/your_theme/favicon.ico. Or replace it with empty favicon.ico.

Comment: ...and start seeing a barrage of 404s in your logs...

Comment: Sure, replace with empty favicon.ico maybe ?

Comment: I think the better solution is to alter the html head and remove the link altogether

Comment: Yes, if you have nothing to link, don't link to anything. Although, simply placing a favicon.ico in the active theme will resolve this. I suspect this person did not clear both Drupal site cache _and_ their browser cache in order to see a new favicon appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default favicon programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/change-default-favicon-programmatically)