# Favicon settings missing on subtheme config

Tags: theming, configuration

Using [Drupal 8 W3CSS Theme 8.x-1.17](https://www.drupal.org/project/d8w3css), I created a subtheme. The subtheme works fine, but on the settings page, the entire `#edit-favicon` div is hidden; `style="display: none"` has been added. I can't figure out why this is happening. However, on the parent theme, the favicon is being displayed. In `subtheme.info.yml`, features and favicon are set to true.

```
settings:
  features:
    favicon: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
settings:
    features:
        favicon: true
    favicon:
        use_default: false
```

Comment: Thanks Armando; I tried this but still don't see favicon on my settings page. I tried pasting in my info file in a comment here but the markdown formatting isn't working for me; I tried single and triple backticks. 

Anyway, I added your suggestion in column one below the features block, is that what you meant? I also flushed all caches, but the settings page is unchanged.

Comment: I've updated the answer, I think this should do

Comment: Those are the settings I've ben using, still hidden. But aha! I found the answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/change-default-favicon-programmatically/184852#184852

Turns out to recognize these changes, flushing caches isn't enough; you must uninstall and reinstall the theme. I don't like that, but it worked. Thanks so much for your suggestions.

Comment: ++ the answer please :)